# Java: entity going from one side to the other within boundaries

Tags: java, if-statement, position, boundary

I am trying to write code for an entity which hops from one side of the page to the other until it reaches a boundary, at which point it turns and hops to the opposite direction. 4 and -4 are my boundaries and also maximum position on either side.

Examples on how position is supposed to change:

- Starting position 0 with direction 2: 0 > 2 > 4 > 2 > 0 > ... But instead I am getting 0 > 2 > 4 > 0 > -2
- Starting position -1 with direction 2: -1 > 1 > 3 > 3 > 1 > ... But instead I am getting -1 > 1 > 3 > 1 > -1

I'm importing my position and direction from a scanner method. This is the part of my code I am having trouble with:

```
    public void methodSample() {

    if (position + direction > 4) {
        position = 8 - (position + direction);
        direction = - direction;
    }

    if (position + direction < -4) {
        position = -8 - (position + direction);
        direction = - direction;
    }

    else {
        position = position + direction;
    }}
```

But I am getting completely irrelevant values when I run the code. It would be great if anyone can spot where I'm going wrong with my code.

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us what irrelevant values you're getting.  Actually, giving us the whole sequence would be helpful.  StackOverflow is a site for asking questions and getting answers.  It's _not_ a site for posing riddles where we have to guess what you're thinking.  And that's what you're doing when you withhold key information.

Comment: Thank you.  Having data makes it easy to spot the problem.  Without the data, I totally missed it even though it should have been obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is something like this:

- If your entity would go off the right edge, then switch direction and go left;
- If your entity would go off the left edge, then switch direction and go right;
- If neither is true, go in the same direction.

However, that's not what's happening.  What really happens is this:

- If your entity would go off the right edge, then switch direction and go left *and then take another step left*.

This is because you're missing an "else".  If `position + direction > 4`, then your program executes the code in the first `if`.  But, since there's no `else` on the second if, the program then continues to the second `if`.  Since `position + direction < -4` is now false, the program executes the `else` part. That means that when you hit the right edge, the program executes *both* the body of the first `if` statement *and* the else part of the second `if` statement.  Changing the second `if` to `else if` will fix this.